# How to get Messages into static method in Seam 3

Tags: dependency-injection, static, cdi, code-injection, seam3

In Seam 2 we have a Component.getInstance(someClass), that can be used into static methods to instanciate a bean.

How do I do this aproach in Seam 3?

Ex:

```
public static someMethod()
{
     SomeClass sc = (SomeClass.class) Component.getInstance(SomeClass.class);
     ...
}
```

and How I get Messages in static methods?

Update:

I used

```
BeanManager beanManager = new BeanManagerLocator().getBeanManager();
Bean<?> bean = beanManager.resolve(beanManager.getBeans(SomeClass.class));
SomeClass sc = (SomeClass) beanManager.getReference(bean, SomeClass.class, beanManager.createCreationalContext(bean));
```

and everything works fine. But all this code have to be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can query the [BeanManager](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html/extend.html#d0e4939) for instances of CDI-beans. This should work in any context, static or not. And it's not Seam 3 specific, BTW

Comment: Mid you're using Seam 3, CODI or DeltaSpike they all have utility classes that do the same boilerplate code.

Answer (score 0):

here http://javalabor.blogspot.in/2011/08/our-seam-2-to-jee-6-replacement-list.html you can find the solution .